# When using the Steam browser protocol, how does Steam locate the .exe to invoke?

Tags: steam

When starting a process via steam://rungameid/###### how does Steam know which .exe to invoke, and with what parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a URI meaning that it is sent to Windows to be handled by some application on your system. In this case, steam has registered all URIs for `steam://` and so, when that gets sent from a browser, steam knows it has to launch a game with that gameid.

As for the [gameid](https://steamdb.info/apps/), Steam knows the gameid as a unique identifier for each game on steam. In this case, 730 is CS:GO and 440 is TF2.

The exe is then run by Steam based on that information. The exe then communicates back with Steam to verify the user's information, achievements, etc. and to verify that Steam is open. This step uses the steam_api.dll file that is present in most Steam game folders.